# Text out of box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter bootstrap and CSS to style a dropdown.  I have a child element that floats on the left and then text that flows to the right of it.  Unfortunately the text does not flow within the containing box and spills over.

I' not sure if this is a Twitter bootstrap issue or just a CSS issue (ultimately a CSS isseu I know but worth tagging this as Twitter Bootstrap too since I'm using that framework).

I've tried several combinations, and obviously not the right combination to achieve the behavior I'm after.  Does anyone know how to fix this?   A working example of the problem is here:

http://ec2-54-215-108-9.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/
(click on the International Gymnast link on the right)

Here is a screenshot demonstrating the issue as well.
[image]
Thanks,

Karl..

Answer (score 1):

Its because links in dropdowns in TWBS have `white-space: nowrap;`.

The easiest solution i could think of is creating a custom CSS class:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a.btn-wrap {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

And then adding `class="btn-wrap"` to your `<a>` element

Comment: `white-space: nowrap*`

Answer (score 1):

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a ,
.btn.btn-default.btn-large.btn-left > span {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

1. I would also reduce the line-height on the a tag.
2. Reduce the height on [.live-mon]
3. Remove the height on the a tag.
4. Increase the padding top and bottom on the a tag.

   ```
   .intl-link li a {
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .intl-link li a {
     line-height: 19px;
   }
   .dropdown-menu.intl-link > li > a {
    padding: 7px 20px;
   }
   .live-mon {
    display: block;
    height: 62px;
    width: 92px;
   }
   ```

You would get something like this:

[image: style cleaning up of message box]

Comment: That would make all buttons wrap spaces, not only the few he wants.

Comment: Reverted to my initial answer.

Comment: I love how the first link looks but I'm not getting the same results as you are.. I lose the float effect, the content falls below the monitor graphic and the overall width is much smaller than this.  I'm still experimenting with this.  For sure, the TWBS no-wrap is the culprit but still need to achieve the nice look.

Comment: I've updated my CSS, default.css, with an acceptable fix.  Thanks for the help.